# Iterator can't access derived class' member methods

Tags: c++

I wish to output the contents of each object from the below vector.

```
vector<Employees*> midzer;
```

The "solution" I found is by doing the following:

```
for (vector<Employees*>::iterator i = midzer.begin(); i != midzer.end(); ++i)
    {
        cout << 
        (*i)->getFirstName() << " " << // Base class method.
        (*i)->getLastName() << "\n" << // Base class method.
        (*i)->getSalary() << "\n" <<   // Base class method.
        (*i)->getNumMeetings() << "\n" << // Derived class method.
        (*i)->getNumVacationDays() << endl; //Derived class method.
    }
```

The issue is that I get an error stating that getNumMeetings and getNumVacationDays are not members of Employees (the base class).

Can anyone elaborate as to why the iterator can't "see" the derived methods and if possible provide a solution for it?

The task is to create a "database" of employees with the functionality to create and delete different types of employees on the fly, and to output the entire database nicely formatted.

Additional info:

- I am only allowed to create one vector.
- I must create a base class and three derived classes (Manager, Engineer and Researcher).

/Kenneth

Comment: That is the way it is. An iterator to a base class has no way of knowing anything about derived types.

Comment: Is `Employees` the base class? If so, could you try casting the iterator to the derived class? (Disclaimer: I've been working with Java a ton recently, and my memory of C++ casting effects is fuzzy at best)

Comment: the good answers are below, but the bad answer is to use a dynamic cast to try and down cast the pointer, then print the extras, from the more specific pointer types, it on those iterations when it succeeds.

Comment: #trojandestroy. If I cast the iterator to the derived class, how will it see the methods of the base class? Employess is the base class.

Answer (score 2):

You can't *see* the base class members because they're *not* there.  You have to cast to the derived type to *use* their members:

```
dynamic_cast<Manager*>(*i)->getNumMeetings() << "\n" <<
```

but a better (more OO) way is to use the class hierarchy to solve the problem -- put a virtual *write* method in the base class and then specialise it in the derived classes.

Comment: I'm in to the OO way, though fairly new. I assume the virtual read method would be something like return (input data member), but I will have three derived classes and when outputting info from all objects (created from different derived classes), will the iterator figure out what to call where?? My guess is no :)

Comment: Of course if the dynamic_cast fails you are calling a method from a null pointer which is undefined behaviour. You may as well invoke undefined behaviour with static_cast if you are going to do that.

Comment: @Kenneth what you really want is simply `cout << *i << endl` and have an `operator<<()` function for each of the derived types.

Comment: What if I'm not to use dynamic cast as proposed by #Paul Evans?

Comment: Sounds simple. I'll go read up on the operator<<() function. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone elaborate as to why the iterator can't "see" the derived methods

Compilation is unaware of virtual function calls, so those functions must exist in `Employees` (better named `Employee`, surely?).

If you're going to use virtual dispatch, all those member functions must be declared in your base class. If they are specific to the derived class, then your design is broken!

Comment: The latter two methods are specific to one of the derived classes (Haven't created the others yet). If the design is broken, do you have an idea how to "fix" the design?

Comment: @Kenneth: Yeah - make a "print" function or something that exists in your base and all your derived types, and have the _implementation_ differ for each as required.

Comment: Will that also work when the outputted objects are in random order.. like researcher, engineer, manager, engineer (...).

I mean with a virtual print function implemented differently in each derived class. which print() do I call with the iterator? Am I explaining my concern well enough?

Comment: @Kenneth: You call the interface's `print()` and let virtual dispatch do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Using polymorphism?

Define a virtual member Print function, taking an ostream. Call it.
Have the derived class version call teh base class version, then print their extra info.

Comment: When you say "taking an ostream" can you provide some sample code please?

Answer (score 0):

It is what we call the Liskov Substitution Principle, which in real terms means that your loop should be valid code for any type of Employees.

If you know that the types are Managers then you really have a vector of pointers to manager.

What you might be looking for is an abstract print function.

```
class Employee
{
public:
     virtual ~Employee();

     virtual std::ostream& print( std::ostream & ) const = 0;
};


class Manager : public Employee
{
public:
      virtual std::ostream& print( std::ostream & ) const;
};

std::ostream& Manager::print( std::ostream & os ) const
{
      // print, knowing I am a Manager
    return os;
}


for (vector<Employees*>::iterator i = midzer.begin(); i != midzer.end(); ++i)
{
    (*i)->print( std::cout );
}
```

If you actually always, within a single vector, have always the same type, you might consider changing your model to reflect these aggregates. A vector of Managers is not a type of vector of Employees, nor the other way round.

Comment: I have both managers, engineers and researchers in the same vector. And they all need to be outputted as the iterator goes through the loop.

Comment: I've implemented your code above. My program compiles but nothing is outputted to console window after creating a Manager. Program just exits normally (exit code 0). Do you have any ideas why that is?

Answer (score 0):

This only works in the opposite direction. So a derived type can "see" the members of its base type (because it **is** the base type), but a base type cannot see the the members of the derived type (because it is **not** the derived type).

A solution would be to implement a function such as "print" or "display" in your base class *Employee*, and then override it in each of your derived classes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't with the iterator but the way you structured your classes.

It's not clear how you defined the Employee class and the subclasses. In Object Oriented Design, the base class contains the interfaces and the sub classes or concrete classes can override/implement the specific behaviors. This is called [program to interface](http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/designprinciples.html) principle. Make use of virtual functions to do this.

Comment: I'll give your link a read. Thanks mate.

The base class contains three general methods which all derived classes use. The derived classes have a few methods specific to their "needs".

Comment: I  hope they do contain `virtual` keywords. Iterator is just a wrapper. Harmless.